# Use the same formula multiple times for multiple cells containing dropdown lists

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

My file looks something like this 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFCqY.png)
An IF statement would be too long considering I have 20 different long formulas.
Update: I later tried to use an IF statement but failed because it depended on substitute function to replace cell references in the equation but substitute returned a string which coudn't be used as a function by IF. 
User should be able to increase available rows by simply copy and insert the previous row.

I can use index match to copy a cell's value which contain the right formula according to the dropdown list but when the user select the same item again I can't update the formula with the new values without affecting the previous cell which used the same formula.
I couldn't find a way to copy the same formula several times and replace cell references in it (without human interaction like search and replace) i.e. by using Substitute function which couldn't replace cell references as it looks through the cell's value not it's formula (the cell which contain the main formula).
Here is one of the 20 formulas I have 
`=(Tables!O167*144/(Tables!O158*Tables!O159)/4005)^2*INDEX(Tables!A159:L200;MATCH(INDEX(Tables!A159:A200;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(Tables!A159:A200>=Tables!O158*Tables!O159/(Tables!O160*Tables!O161);0);));Tables!A159:A200;0)+MATCH(INDEX(Tables!B159:B200;MATCH(INDEX(Tables!A159:A200;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(Tables!A159:A200>=Tables!O158*Tables!O159/(Tables!O160*Tables!O161);0);));Tables!A159:A200;0)+MATCH(INDEX(Tables!B159:B200;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(Tables!B159:B200>=Tables!O164/(2*Tables!O158*Tables!O159/(Tables!O158+Tables!O159));0);));Tables!B159:B200;0)-1;);Tables!B159:B200;0)-1;MATCH((INDEX(Tables!C158:L158;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(Tables!C158:L158>=Tables!O163;0);)));Tables!A158:L158;0))`
I tried to use FORMULATEXT to convert the formula into a string then use substitute to replace the cell references then use the depreciated Evaluation function but hit the 255 char limit.
 I searched a lot on google but to no avail, I don't mind a VBA code but a macro free method would be better, Thanks.

TL;DR: Is there a way to copy a formula stored in a cell and replace some of the cell references then enter it in another cell multiple times with different cell references each time ??

Comment: I gather than H2:J2 is actually B2:D2 but why isn't the square formula =H2^2?

Comment: It's just an example it's not really a square formula and most of the cell references are from another sheet with 3 to 5 cell references that need to be changed with the cells that the user will fill

Comment: fwiw, isn't *x* typically the base, not the height? Might be confusing in its current form.

Comment: Make the jump to VBA or Python; you'll be happier for it. Programming in Excel formulas is fun and accessible, but the limitations quickly pile up into something horrible.

Comment: jumping into VBA is something that I will have to do eventually but I can't right now and for sure I can't start learning VBA to accomplish this goal and expect quick results :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in E2 and fill down.

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(LOWER(LEFT(A2)), {"r","s","t"}, 0), B2*C2, B2^2, B2*C2/2)
```

[image]

Comment: I can't verify it right now since I have to sleep atm but does your formula means that I will have to enter all my 20 formulas in this arrangement 
please keep in mind that not all the cells X,Y and Z etc will be used in all the formulas some will be used others will not and so on.

Comment: Well, I guess they have to be somewhere. If not in the formula then they would have to evaluated from a text based list.

Comment: evaluated as in using the depreciated evaluate function ?? if so I tried to use it and hit the 255 char limit so hard :(

Comment: Then you need to write a 'Swiss Army knife' type UDF with a select case that will handle whichever of the 20-odd maths you want to process.

Comment: :( not helping man so what you want to tell me is that I hit the basic formulas limit ??

Comment: Using your variable's x, y, & z, what is the longest formula? (Please show the formula).

Comment: Based on your response, there are multiple different possible entries depending on the formula selected and these entries may not be just x, y, & z.  It appears that a user could have multiple other variables as would be needed for the selected formula in a different part of the sheet entirely.    
As to the 255 limit, using named ranges may reduce your formula length and increase readability.  
You can use substitute for the replace values/references in formulas - look at indirect()

Comment: @Jbowman I left an example in my post and in this pic (it's the same formula but in it's original sheet) I have marked the variables that the user will enter in the calculation sheet i.imgur.com/s8Lf8Sn.png

Comment: yeah I tried to combine indirect with substitute that was my initial plan but couldn't get it right maybe I was doing something wrong but I tried to use indirect to get the formula from the cell then substitute to replace the cell references

Comment: as for the named ranges I tried to use it but it was bothersome maybe I will resort to it in the end but I can't be sure that it will overcome the 255 char limit

Comment: yep as I thought named ranges won't solve this problem as the cell references that need to be changed are inside almost every functions' arguments

Comment: Ok.  your Post "image" looks like your using `b2:d2` to gather the formula parameters/values, but the image `i.imgur.com/s8Lf8Sn.png` is gathering the parameters/value from an entirely different part of the sheet (O158:O161), which does not appear to use the values from `b2:d2`.  How does O158:O167 (?) get populated?

Comment: As I said before the image in the post is just an example the actual sheet has more cells for entering values and what i want to do is replace each constant cell reference from the original sheet with another variable incremental cell reference (as the row number increase) in the new sheet